# Topology not working due to Found multiple defaults.yaml resources when deploying to remote cluster

Tags: build.gradle, apache-storm

I have a single node remote cluster set up (all nimbus , supervisor , zookeeper) running on the same machine  . I deployed my Topology (simple Exclamation Topology) to this remote cluster . While topology and jar got submitted successfully , nothing is happening in the cluster .

When I checked the supervisor logs , I could see this :
2015-10-14T21:24:26.340+0000 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] 42dd0337-1182-45b0-9385-14570c7e0b09 still hasn't started

Worker log files are empty .

On debugging a little in supervisor logs , I could see 
Launching worker with command: (Some java command) ..Firing this java command I can see this error :

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar.

I debugged more on internet and other stuff , and modified my build.gradle file too but still the same error whenever I deploy my topology .

This is my gradle file

```
dependencies {

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: springBootVersion

    compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: quartzVersion

compile group: 'clj-stacktrace' , name: 'clj-stacktrace',version: cljStackTrace

compile group: 'org.apache.storm' , name: 'storm-core',version: stormVersion

    ext {

      fatJarExclude = true

  }

}
task uberjar(type: Jar) {

from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)

from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}} {

    exclude "META-INF/*.SF"

    exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"

    exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"

    exclude "META-INF/LICENSE"
}
manifest {

attributes 'Main-Class': 'storm.topology.ExclamationTopology'
}
}
```

Comment: how can you exclude "defaults.yaml" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar file must not contain `defaults.yaml` file. Thus, you need to exclude it via

```
exclude "defaults.yaml"
```

Actually I would recommend the exclude all Storm dependencies from your jar. They are not needed and increase the size of the fat jar unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes u r correct :) . Thanks  .. I solved it by following this "http://kennethjorgensen.com/blog/2014/fat-jars-with-excluded-dependencies-in-gradle"  . Also Matthias , I believe this should be included in storm documentation so that ppl dont end up wasting time like me :)

Comment: Maybe it should be added. Just open a pull request for it ;) I am pretty sure the Storm people will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1- Delete using winrar "defaults.yaml" in the .jar

2- adding in the pom.xml storm-core as provided.

In my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1-incubating</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

When packaging your topology jar, don't include the Storm jars as Storm will put those on the classpath for you.

Reference

http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.2/Troubleshooting.html

Comment: Your reference link is broken